# Modify program below to accept both letters and numbers

Tags: excel, vba

```
Public Function CheckForNumChar(Text As String) As Boolean
```

Abstract: This Function checks a character for an NUMERIC character
Input Parameters: Char = Character to check
Output Parameters: True if Numeric or False if Not Numeric

```
 Dim Length, prompt, Char As String
    Dim response
    Dim I As Integer

    Length = Len(Text)  'Check length of string
    For I = 1 To Length Step 1
    CheckForNumChar = ((Mid(Text, I, Length) Like "[0-9]*")) 'Checks for number
    `enter code here`If CheckForNumChar Then
            Else 'Character is not Numeric
    prompt = "Only Numeric Characters Are Permitted In This Field"    'MsgBox string
                response = MsgBox(prompt, vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Character 

Check")             'MsgBox
            SendKeys "{Bs}", True       'Backspace
            Exit Function
    End If
Next I
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `[0-9]*` to `[A-Za-z0-9]*`.

For reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

> Multiple Character Ranges
>
> To specify multiple ranges for the same character position, put them within the same brackets without delimiters. For example, [A–CX–Z] results in a match if the corresponding character position in string contains any character within either the range A–C or the range X–Z.